# Почему не открывается модальное окно?

Tags: html, jquery, jsp, spring-boot

Сделал модальное окно с помощью jquery. Весь html код располагается на jsp странице, также использую spring-boot, tomcat.

```
<button class="button js-button-campaign">Click</button>//кнопка при нажатии на которую должно всплыть окно

<div class="overlay js-overlay-campaign">//Подложка для окна
   <div class="popup js-popup-campaign" >//само окно
        //Здесь просто форма для отправки на рест сервер.        
        <div class="close-popup js-close-campaign"></div>//чтобы можно было закрыть окно
   </div>
</div>
```

Вот код jquery, который лежит в отдельно файле, файл подключаю к jsp странице. Хотя я размещал его и просто в head-теге, ничего не менялось.

```
// открыть по кнопке
$('.js-button-campaign').click(function() { 
    $('.js-overlay-campaign').fadeIn();
    $('.js-overlay-campaign').addClass('disabled');
});

// закрыть на крестик
$('.js-close-campaign').click(function() { 
    $('.js-overlay-campaign').fadeOut();

});
```

Когда нажимаю на кнопку - ничего не проиходит.Проверил код просто в обычном html документе, куда подключил все необходимые ресурсы - все работает. Что не так может быть с jsp или spring-boot'ом? В чем может быть дело?

Дополнение:
У меня есть jsp страница, которая отображает таблицу, данные таблицы приходят из бд, их присылает RestController в виде json я его парсю и отображаю в виде таблицы. Я хочу использовать подход ajax, и использую, т.о:

```
       <script>
            var LIST_PRODUCTS = "/listProducts";

            $(document).ready(function() {

                var table = $('table');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: LIST_PRODUCTS,
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: true,
                    success: function (result) {
                        for(var i in result) {
                            var str = "<tr>";
                            for(var prop in result[i]){
                                str += "<td>" + result[i][prop] + "</td>";
                            }
                            str += "</tr>";
                            table.append(str);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Exception");
                    }
                });

            });
        </script>
```

Из этого вырисовывается нужная мне таблица, код, который отвечает за вызов всплывающей формы, был просто в теге `head` в `<script></script>` и не работало. Когда перенес код оттуда, и вставил его сразу после загрузки таблицы все начало работать. А если я хочу не хочу это все скидывать в одну кучу, в один `script`, а хочу раскидать по файлам, нужно везде писать код jquery в `$(document).ready(function(){})` или как? Если я написал что-то глупое, то сорри, буквально сегодня начал пользовать js и jq.
Вот так у меня выглядит сейчас секция `head`, если перенесу методы открытия/закрытия попап окна в `script` где находится `$(document).ready(function(){})`, то начинает все работать:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/WEB-INF/resources/js/popupWindow.js"></script>

        <script>
            var LIST_PRODUCTS = "/listProducts";

            $(document).ready(function() {

                var table = $('table');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: LIST_PRODUCTS,
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: true,
                    success: function (result) {
                        for(var i in result) {
                            var str = "<tr>";
                            for(var prop in result[i]){
                                str += "<td>" + result[i][prop] + "</td>";
                            }
                            str += "</tr>";
                            table.append(str);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Exception");
                    }
                });

            });
        </script>

        <script>
            $('#create_date').mask('11/11/1111');
        </script>

        <script>
            //МЕТОДЫ ОТКРЫТИЯ/ЗАКРЫТИЯ
            $('.js-button-campaign').click(function() {

                $('.js-overlay-campaign').fadeIn();
                $('.js-overlay-campaign').addClass('disabled');
            });

            // закрыть на крестик
            $('.js-close-campaign').click(function() {
                $('.js-overlay-campaign').fadeOut();

            });
        </script>
```

Comment: откройте результат в отладчике браузера и скопируйте сюда

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.js-button-campaign').click(function() {
  $('.js-overlay-campaign').fadeIn();
  $('.js-overlay-campaign').addClass('disabled');
});

// закрыть на крестик
$('.js-close-campaign').click(function() {
  $('.js-overlay-campaign').fadeOut();

});
```

```css
.overlay{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.popup{
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button js-button-campaign">Click</button>
<div class="overlay js-overlay-campaign">
  <div class="popup js-popup-campaign">
    <div class="close-popup js-close-campaign">x</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

У вас всё работает, смотрите консоль и дополняйте свой вопрос. Никто не даст ответа, можно лишь догадываться, не более чем.

Предоставьте больше информации.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ваше сообщение. Оно навело меня на одну мысль, я кое-что исправил и все заработало. Только я не совсем понимаю почему. Я щас дополню ответ, если вы сможете объяснить почему не работало, буду очень признателен.

Comment: @MaksOhotnikov можно увидеть данные которые приходят через ajax? Возможно у вас проблема в том, что скрипт сканирует все элементы с начала загрузки страницы, а потом когда всё уже загрузилось вы добавляете новые поля, которых нет в сканировании, проще говоря необходимо сделать клик по элементу подобным образом : **$(document).on('click', '.js-close-campaign', function() {});**

Comment: через ajax приходит просто два объекта в json формате. Я еще не сделал возможность добавлять что-то, когда захожу на страницу у меня просто приходят данные и сразу же отображаются и все. Эту форму как раз делаю для того, чтобы можно было добавлять данные в таблицу.

Comment: Вот, что конкретно приходит: `[{"id":0,"name":"name","description":"no","create_date":"2019-04-24","place_storage":4,"reserved":true},{"id":1,"name":"имя","description":"нет","create_date":"2019-04-24","place_storage":4,"reserved":false}]`